# PDO Update statement, work in PHPmyadmin but not in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, database-connection

I am trying to make an update statement with PDO and i found out it doesn´t work.

I have testet the SQL statement in phpMyadmin and it works if i put '' arround the passkey, but why wont it work with this ?

INFO: 
The passkey is a md5 string

```
 <?php

include('../mysql/pdoconn.php');

$passkey = $_GET['passkey'];

$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE user SET com_code='' WHERE com_code = :passkey");
$stmt->bindParam(':passkey', $passkey , PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute;
$error = "Jon Snow";

$stmt1 = $conn->prepare("SELECT com_code from user where com_code =''");
$stmt1->execute;
$result = $stmt1->fetchColumn();


if($result === "")
{
     $error = 'Your account is now active. You may now <a href="../signin/sign.php">Log in</a>';
    $conn = null;
} else
{
    $error = $passkey;
    $conn = null;
}
?>
```

i have tested that it gets the passkey, and it does, but it dont update the table...

I have tried anything, but i cant get it to work

Comment: You're using a bound parameter. You don't need to quote bound parameters - that's taken care of for you when you execute it.

Comment: even if i try withput the '' it does´nt work

Comment: `$stmt->execute;` should be `$stmt->execute();`. it is a function you also should check for errors. If you quote the placeholder you make it into a string, not a placeholder.

Comment: thanks it works..
Newbie, i am

Comment: Inside the included file where you define `$conn = new PDO(...)` turn on PDO's exception reporting. by default it errors silently, and is easy to miss things.  Right after defining `$conn` do `$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`  The errors will become clear more easily. Also, always when developing and testing code, enable PHP's error display:  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Where are these reports saved ? i mean from PDO ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE user SET com_code='' WHERE com_code = :passkey");
$stmt->bindParam(':passkey', $passkey , PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
```

1. `execute()` is a function
2. You don't need to quote bound parameters

Comment: Brilliant, it works ! Thanks M8. i did´nt see it.
Newbie, i am.